# Calling php block inside other block in if statement

Tags: php, swiper.js

Im having a problem. Using swiper.js control arrows

```
<?= ($block->getData('controls') == "1") ? '<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-slide-<?= $_uniqid ?>"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next-slide-<?=$_uniqid?>"></div>':'<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-hidden"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-hidden"></div>'?>
```

Im using this code to retrieve the value 1 that make those two divs appear and if the value is 0 the other two divs appears. It works well but in the case that the controls are equal to 1 my arrows dont work they just appear but i cant interact with them and this is why

```
navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-next-slide-<?= $_uniqid ?>',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-prev-slide-<?= $_uniqid ?>',
            },
```

this is my swipper object the interaction with the arrows possible . As you can see the nextEl and prevEl values are the same as the div class. I think the problem is in the uniqid because is not being read properly in the class inside the php block

Comment: Did you check the console for JS related errors?. or try once by place static value instead of $_uniqid

Comment: @abhay is doesnt give me any errors related with this issue i think php its no very good at doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems syntax error in your code. Please see updated code below.

```
    <?= ($block->getData('controls') == "1") ? '<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-slide-'.$_uniqid.'"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-next-slide-'.$_uniqid.'"></div>':'<div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-hidden"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-hidden"></div>'?>
```

Comment: Please confirm, is this resolved your issue or I can serve better other way?